# FBSDK 9.0.1 Error: dispatch_once IOS Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, fbsdk

I updated FacebookSDK from 7.0.1 to 9.0.1 using Cocoapods, and I am getting an error in this method:

```
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate, dispatch_block_t block)
    {
      if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried my ways but issue not resolved. Then I install 8.2.0 and it works fine